# Case insensitive query in PHP does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table: `id, name(text, utf8_general_ci)`.

Simple data into table: `1, LOlKek_228666`

Trying PHP:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
mysqli_set_charset('utf8',$link);
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `commands` WHERE LOWER(`name`) = LOWER('$nick') ORDER BY id DESC");
```

or simple:

```
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `commands` WHERE `name` = '$nick' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

It can't find any if use `LolKek_228666` (to find `LOlKek_228666`)  in query($nick).
But phpmyadmin find it. How to fix that?

Comment: No errors are thrown? What does `"SELECT * FROM commands WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER('$nick') ORDER BY id DESC"` output as? If you put the static value in does it work?

Comment: $q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `commands` WHERE `name` = 'LolKek_228666' ORDER BY id DESC"); this can't find any (or use "LIKE")

Comment: And `$link` is a connection to the same server, db, you are running the phpmyadmin with? Whats `$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) FROM commands";` give back on phpmyadmin and in your script?

Comment: My script finds a value if I use exactly the same as in the database. I do not know what's the matter, maybe in encodings or something else

Comment: Oh? I thought your comment 8 minutes ago said it wasn't found. What does `$nick` output as with `var_dump`?

Comment: var_dump: string(13) "LolKek_228666"

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a case-insensitive collation, you might just go with using the "LIKE" operator and drop the LOWER() functions.

WHERE LOWER(`name`) will just lowercase the fieldname, not the data value.

Comment: $q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `commands` WHERE `name` LIKE '$nick' ORDER BY id DESC"); this doesn't work. I have missed something else. For some reason, everything in the phpmyadmin works easily. @sturmfrisur

Comment: In phpMyAdmin, on the SQL tab, after a query is run there is an option to "Create PHP Code".  What does the output show that does not match yours?